# grep flag to NOT ignore case

Tags: shell-script, grep, gnu, options, case-sensitivity

I have a simple script to search patterns in my code sources, named `prgrep`

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
grep -irnI --exclude-dir={.git,obj} --exclude=tags --color=auto "$@"
```

(The fact that it is a script and not an alias or function is that I want to be able to call it from inside `vim` and with any shell)

Note that the search is case insensitive (since I consider this a good default to search) and the script accepts any flags that `grep` accepts.

I would like `grep` to have a flag `--no-ignore-case` so that the caller of the script could override the `-i` flag of the script, but `GNU grep` does not provide this.

Do you have any simple idea to provide such functionality? Currently I have a separate script named `Prgrep` which performs case sensitive searches.

**EDIT**
Recent versions of `GNU grep` do provide a `--no-ignore-case` option, which is exactly what I need. I'm using `GNU grep 3.1`, which still doesn't have this option.

Comment: How about an argument for the script? Inside the script you check `$1` for any string you like and create a case statement with or without case-sensitive search.

Comment: The desired behaviour is achieved simply by dropping `-i` -  I don't understand what the question is.

Comment: @eblock That would force a predefined number of arguments, and the script would have to handle all of them. I want to keep allowing all the `grep` options

Comment: @Panki I want case insentitive search by default and provide an option to force a case sensitive search. Dropping `-i` would make all searches case sensitive

Comment: Ok, I didn't realize that I was using an old version of `grep`. My Linux box is using GNU grep 3.1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was fixed by updating grep.

Comment: @Panki OK, but it would be nice to have a solution for old versions of grep...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New versions of `grep` have the option `--no-ignore-case` which overrides `-i`:

> **--no-ignore-case**
> Do not ignore case distinctions in patterns and input data.  This is the default.  This option is useful for passing to shell scripts that already use -i, to cancel its effects because the two options override each other.

For older versions of `grep`, you could simply add this as option to your script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = "--no-ignore-case" ]; then
    shift
    grep -rnI --exclude-dir={.git,obj} --exclude=tags --color=auto "$@"
else
    grep -irnI --exclude-dir={.git,obj} --exclude=tags --color=auto "$@"
fi
```

Note: `--no-ignore-case` will need to be  the first argument when you call your script.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that `--no-ignore-case` must always be the first argument in order to be matched

Comment: @Hobber short of re-doing the entire argument parsing of `grep`, there's no way to robustly handle that. Consider a command line like `your_wrapper -hio --no-ignore-case ...`: the `--no-ignore-case` should override not only the `-i` default from your wrapper, but also the `-i` from the command line, which means that it will have to parse and rebuild the command line of `grep`; have a look at the `/usr/bin/zgrep` wrapper script on Linux to have a taste of what that entails ;-)